# Why chrome Devtools performance recording doesn't show some invoked functions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, v8

The following code may not be suitable for the real world, but it shows this problem well. if you run this code, 123456789 will be printed correctly in the output but you can't find all the corresponding logger function of 1-9 in Chrome Devtools performance recording. I also enabled the "advanced print instrumentation" option, but it didn't make a difference.

How can I make sure that all functions executed in this operation will be displayed?

```js
function logger1() {
    for (var n = 0; n < 1e4; n++) {}
    console.log(1)
}
function logger2() {
    for (var n = 0; n < 1e4; n++) {}
    console.log(2)
}
function logger3() {
    for (var n = 0; n < 1e4; n++) {}
    console.log(3)
}
function logger4() {
    for (var n = 0; n < 1e4; n++) {}
    console.log(4)
}
function logger5() {
    for (var n = 0; n < 1e4; n++) {}
    console.log(5)
}
function logger6() {
    for (var n = 0; n < 1e4; n++) {}
    console.log(6)
}
function logger7() {
    for (var n = 0; n < 1e4; n++) {}
    console.log(7)
}
function logger8() {
    for (var n = 0; n < 1e4; n++) {}
    console.log(8)
}
function logger9() {
    for (var n = 0; n < 1e4; n++) {}
    console.log(9)
}
function logger10() {
    for (var n = 0; n < 1e4; n++) {}
    console.log(10)
}

function myCode() {
    const afn = new Promise(function promiseCallback(rs) {
        logger1()
        setTimeout(function timeOutCallBack() {
            logger6()
            rs("afn done")
            logger7()
        }, 1000)
        logger2()
    })

    async function myFm() {
        logger4()
        await afn
        logger8()
    }

    logger3()
    myFm()
        .then(function thenCallback() {
            logger9()
        })
        .catch(function catchCallback(e) {
            logger10()
            console.error(e)
        })
    logger5()
}

setTimeout(myCode, 1000)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Profiling is based on sampling: with a certain frequency (I believe every 0.1ms, but I'm not entirely sure), the current call stack is sampled. Functions that run long enough or often enough have a very high statistical probability of being encountered by these samples, with a frequency that correlates with the amount of time being spent in them. Very short-running functions might not be caught by any sample.

To put that into practical terms: for a toy example, to make sure all functions show up on the profile, make them run longer.
For real-world situations, if a function isn't showing up on the profile, then it ran so quickly that it's not a performance bottleneck worth worrying about. The profile *will* show you any function that consumed significant amounts of time.

Comment: That's right, when I changed the number of loops from 1e4 to 1e9 and the processing time increased, all the loggers functions appeared.

Comment: There is a command-line option for V8: --cpu-profiler-sampling-interval - CPU profiler sampling interval in microseconds. It shows the default interval for Node.js v16 as 1000 microseconds, i.e. 1ms.

Comment: "The profile will show you any function that consumed significant amounts of time" In theory, there could be a short function which runs every 1ms or any other exact amount of milliseconds (e.g. in games). It can accidentally hide from profiling when sampling is started right between two executions of that function.

Comment: @Victor: yes, both `d8` and Node sample every 1ms by default. I believe DevTools samples more frequently, but as I said I'm not sure. Regarding accidental hiding: if a function takes, say, 5% of the overall time but distributed over very many individual invocations taking just 10μs each, then if you sample for a few seconds it _should_ statistically show up for around 5% of the collected ticks, even though only a minority of its individual calls were sampled.

Comment: @jmrk you missed the idea: if the function is somehow synchronised with the sampling interval e.g. they both run every 1ms, but sampling happens exactly at 1.0ms, 2.0ms, 3.0ms etc., and function runs from 1.1ms to 1.2ms, from 2.1ms to 2.2ms, from 3.1ms to 3.2ms etc., then this function will be invisible in samples. It is mostly pure theory because in practice I've never seen such functions, but forewarned == forearmed. Of course, if the function is not synchronised (as it usually happens) - then it will inevitably show up in profile no matter how short it is.

Comment: @Victor right, theoretically that could happen, but as you say, in practice it's very unlikely. I suppose it's a reason not to make the sampler run at the same 60 Hz as a typical screen refresh / animation frame rate :)